# cucumber stepdefinition file is not recognized by the protractor cucumber config file

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

unable to execute the steps in the step definition file

i tried the solutions present in the google but none of them are answer my questions.

### my Config file

```
  //seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  directConnect: true,
  //specs: ['/Users/bharaniravisankar/Desktop/PRO/SPECS/TEST.JS'],
  framework: 'custom',
  // path relative to the current config file
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },
  specs: [
    '/Users/bharaniravisankar/Desktop/PRO/Feature/test.feature'
  ],

  cucumberOpts: {
    require: '/Users/bharaniravisankar/Desktop/PRO/Feature/Step Definition/login.js',
    //tags: false,
    //format: 'pretty',
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true
  }

};
```

### my console log

```
? Given User navigate to Home Page
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         Given('User navigate to Home Page', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });

   ? When User enter email and other details
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         When('User enter email and other details', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });

   ? And click on Submit button
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         When('click on Submit button', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });

   ? Then Login is created sucessfully
       Undefined. Implement with the following snippet:

         Then('Login is created sucessfully', function () {
           // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
           return 'pending';
         });

   ✔ After # CONG.js/node_modules/protractor-cucumber-framework/lib/resultsCapturer.js:26

1 scenario (1 undefined)
4 steps (4 undefined)
```

### Stepdefinition file

```
var { Given, When, Then } = require("cucumber");

module.exports = function () {

    this.Given(/^User navigate to Home Page$/, async function () {
     // this.When('User enter email and other details', function () {

        //launch AWS portal
        browser.get('https://portal.aws.amazon.com/billing/signup#/start');

        //Maximize the browser window
        browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //Check the title of the Webpage
       expect(await browser.getTitle()).toEqual('AWS Console - Signup');


      });

      this.When(/^User enter email and other details$/, function () {
      //  this.When('User enter email and other details', function () {

        element(by.model('credentials.email')).sendKeys('bharaniravi36@gmail.com')
        element(by.model('credentials.password')).sendKeys('Feb%1992');
        element(by.model('credentials.rePassword')).sendKeys('Feb%1992');
        element(by.model('credentials.fullName')).sendKeys('bharaniravi85');

      });



      //this.When('click on Submit button', function () {

        this.When(/^click on Submit button$/, function () {

        element(by.xpath("(//input[@class='a-button-input'])[1]")).click();
      });

      this.Then(/^Login is created sucessfully$/, function () {

        expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('AWS Console - Signup');
        element(by.id('company')).sendKeys('POLI');

        //click on country drop down
        element(by.model("address.countryCode")).click();
        element(by.xpath("//option[@label='American Samoa']")).click();
              // add sleep to give a time for te options to reveal
              browser.sleep(3000)
      });
  };
```

in my research i didnt miss anything in my setup and every thing is setup in my system and required dependencies are downloaded.

Comment: do you know the version of cucumber you are using?

Answer (score 0):

First of all try creating the step definition folder outside the feature folder to keep separation of features and step definitions and folder name should be without spaces like 'stepdefinition'.

Secondly, make sure all the feature steps should be implemented in the step definition file and the text of each step should be the same as mentioned in the features.

Try using this and let me know, if it works for you.

Comment: Still facing same issue

Comment: updated step definition file.. can you please refresh it and check the issue description

Comment: this.Given(/^User navigate to Home Page$/, async function () - make sure to remove the characters from the steps and write in this way this.Given(User navigate to Home Page, async function () and then try

Comment: If i use the the statement like this Given(User navigate to Home Page, async function (). it is throwing error code as 12:55:36] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[12:55:36] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[12:55:40] E/launcher - Error: /Users/bharaniravisankar/Desktop/PRO/stepdefinition/login.js:5
    this.Given(User navigate to Home Page,  function () {
               ^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: I have tried the whole piece of code and it is working on my end, there may be some sort of configuration issue.

Comment: Ok. Can u please share the configuration needed for using cucumber framework in protractor in visual stdio code IDE. Because i am new to protractor.

Comment: or else can you please let me know what might be that missed configuration and what all are you configured.

Comment: did anybody have an idea how to reslove this

Comment: Let me check this again and get back to you.

Comment: I have again checked and have following observations addition to previous ones. 1) Remove code block 'module.exports = function () {' in step definition and write your code without the exports. 2) Remove 'this' keyword from when, then given keywords. 3) String mentioned inside the given, when and then keywords should be in single quotes like Given('User navigate to Home Page', async function ()

Comment: Done the changes which you have mentioned and it is working perfectly now. Thanks for your valuable commends.

Comment: can you give rating to my answer by pressing the up arrow key, it will be appreciable.